# Verify signature with builtin python ssl module

Tags: python, ssl

Is there a way to use the builtin `ssl` module to verify signatures?

In theory, it seems like this is possible because `ssl` must be able to verify ssl message signatures. But I don't see any public interface for doing simple digital signature verification.

Ultimately, I just want to have a function similar to the [PyOpenSSL one](http://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#signing-and-verifying-signatures):

`OpenSSL.crypto.verify(certificate, signature, data, digest)`

For reference, here's an example of using the PyOpenSSL sign/verify function: https://github.com/calebmadrigal/p2p-signed-keyval-lookup/blob/master/prototypes/sign_verify_test.py

Comment: I do not see any public interface for that either (the signature handling is probably done inside the openssl library that it wraps, not even in the Python part), so why do you absolutely need to do this with the `ssl` module and not something else?